# Statistical test for rare events in meta-analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, rare-events

As a pedagogical work, I am planning to perform a meta-analysis with a rare event as the primary outcome.
Here is the type of data I plan to collect (the numbers here are fictive):

| study | no. events in control group | no. events in intervention group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/253 | 0/189 |
| 2 | 0/42 | 1/157 |
| 3 | 5/221 | 0/318 |
| 4 | 2/228 | 0/159 |

I have no reason to think that the studies are homogeneous, therefore a random model effect would be more appropriate.
Because of the possibility that there will be groups with 0 event, I cannot always calculate the relative risks.
In this case, **what particular statistical test would be the most appropriate to evaluate the differential repartition of events between control and intervention groups?**

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this Q&A help? It is about using odds ratios with zero cells but the references may be of benefit https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256905/meta-analysis-when-an-or-goes-to-infinity/256919#256919

Comment: @mdewey it does indeed help! Thank you very much

Comment: Further to the great advice above, here is a link to the Cochrane Handbook where it discusses rare events (https://training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/chapter-10#section-10-4-4) and a paper on exact vs. asymptomatic methods for meta-analysis of rare events (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0962280208092559).